# CRM 2011 outlook client crashing on replying emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, dynamics-crm

We have configured CRM 2011 plugin for outlook(CRM RU8, Outlook 2010). Its working fine for all the users except one. From one user machine, able to send a new mail but whenever we try to reply to mails, outlook getting crashed and asking to close the program. If we disable the CRM add-in, its working fine and able to reply to mails. Can any one help me to fix this issue?

Comment: From @Abhilash Panicker: Please turn on "Error" level Diagnostics for CRM client for Outlook and paste the results here. Also do capture the event logs from the machine and share so that we can check.